# Making content accessible on Addon SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing an addon using Firefox's Addon SDK (v. 1.11). My extension dynamically creates an iframe on each website and then loads an html file which includes other resources such as images, font files, etc. from the add on's local directory.

**Problem**

When loading any of such local resources (i.e.: "*resource://*" schema), the iframe fails to display them and a message is thrown:

> Security Error: Content at http: //www.XXX may not load or link to
>   resource://XXX

This is a security measure [introduced on Firefox 3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration#contentaccessible). When developing without the Addon SDK, the way around it is declaring a directory with "contentaccessible=yes", making the directory's contents accessible to anyone, including my add on. However, I have not been able to find similar functionality using the Addon SDK. Is there a better way of using local data on an iframe that my addon creates and inserts into a page?

Comment: Have you found any solution ? I'm stuck at the same..

Comment: me, too. webfonts don’t work…

Comment: @josesigna possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30051158/669721

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can directly load an iFrame that points to a resource inside your URL. The browser complains because it's either breaking same origin policy or cross site scripting one. I can't remember which one right now.

if it is html content you want to load you can always inject it into the DOM and then send a message to the document object using the events API to display your custom html. I've done this in the past and it works.

so from main.js send a message to content script which will then inject your iframe html into the DOM and then you can send the document object a message to display it.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this was the case when you posted the question, but it appears that "resource://" should no longer be used with the Addon SDK.

If you're using the resource inside of an HTML file in the extension, you can reference it locally, otherwise you should use data.url('whatever.jpg') and pass around that value as needed.

Full info is here: http://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/01/11/sdk-1-4-known-issue-with-hard-coding-resource-uris/

Comment: That info seems to be outdated and the link at the end that would help is dead

Comment: @rubo77 the link in the comments is dead now because Builder is gone :-/ hmm.  Which info appears to be outdated?

Comment: your link still works, but on that page at the end that link is dead: `Jeff Griffiths Author

    Hi John!

    Sorry – builder changed all of its urls at some point and failed to do forwards properly.

    That example is now here:
`
    https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/40222/latest/ - but that link is dead too

Comment: @rubo77 yeah, that link is dead because Builder is retired now. Aside from the link in the comment being broken, is there something specific you're wondering about, or does any of the info on the page seem out of date? Happy to try to help clear up any confusion :)

Comment: i just thoutgh a running example would be nice.  and exactly that is missing now

Comment: I see still resource:// urls dont load on iframe for addons. Is there any way I can make this iframe load on a webpage. The page I want to load on does block data: through its CSP. I need help to get this work.