# how to append iframe to hosted page using Firefox SDK addon?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Assume `frame.html` inside data folder in Firefox SDK addon,
how to append an iframe and define `frame.html` as its source?

Additional info:
Because of CPS, its not possible to use inline source, so I can't use `data.load('frame.html')`, I need to use URL of the file:

lib/main.js

```
tabs.activeTab.attach({
  contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("js/appender.js") ],
  attachTo: 'top',
  contentScriptOptions: {
    scriptUrl: self.data.url("js/sandbox.js"),
    imageUrl: self.data.url("image.jpg")
    frameUrl: self.data.url("sandbox.html")
  }
});
```

data/appender.js

```
  var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
  scriptTag.src = self.options.scriptUrl;
  document.body.appendChild(scriptTag); // worked fine

  var imageTag = document.createElement("image");
  imageTag.src = self.options.imageUrl;
  document.body.appendChild(imageTag); // worked fine

  var iframeTag = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframeTag.src = self.options.frameUrl;
  document.body.appendChild(iframeTag); // the html tag of iframe is empty
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's blank because of the firefox security policy which doens't allow  content scripts to load resources URLs as iframes. The solution could be to set it directly from the background script, for this you'll need to use low level sdk.

```
var { viewFor } = require("sdk/view/core");
var tab_utils = require("sdk/tabs/utils");

var iframe = viewFor(tab).linkedBrowser._contentWindow.document.querySelector('iframe[src="' + self.data.url("sandbox.html") + '"]')
iframe.contentWindow.location.href = iframe.getAttribute("src")
```

so the completely working code would look like:

data/appender.js

```
var iframeTag = document.createElement("iframe");
iframeTag.src = self.options.frameUrl;
document.body.appendChild(iframeTag); // the html tag of iframe is empty

// note that the iframe is attached after the content ready event, so you have to inform the background when it can start working with the iframe
self.port.emit("attached", true);
```

main.js

```
tabs = require("sdk/tabs")
self = require("sdk/self")

var { viewFor } = require("sdk/view/core");
tab_utils = require("sdk/tabs/utils");

tabs.on("ready", function(tab) {
  var worker = tab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("js/appender.js") ],
    attachTo: 'top',
    contentScriptOptions: {
      frameUrl: self.data.url("sandbox.html")
    }
  });

  worker.port.on('attached', function() {
    reinitIframe(tab)
  });

  function reinitIframe(tab) {
    var iframe = viewFor(tab).linkedBrowser._contentWindow.document.querySelector('iframe[src="' + self.data.url("sandbox.html") + '"]')
    iframe.contentWindow.location.href = iframe.getAttribute("src")
  }
})
```

You'll probably need a [cross-process wrapper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/Cross_Process_Object_Wrappers) in order to make it work in future version of Firefox with electrolysis

Comment: You saved us from a headache.

Comment: I've used this, working. but why I can not postMessage to this iframe?

Comment: @alihaghighatkhah it should be possible from your content script

Comment: tragically! it's not. I dispatched custom events instead.

Answer (score 0):

Found a better way. You add a blank `<iframe>` and attach an event listener for the `load` event. Then you can easily append whatever elements you want to the iframe as usual.

Include this in your content-script:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe'),
  div = document.createElement('div');
div.textContent('Hello World');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.addEventListener('load', function(){
  this.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(div)
})
```