# Firefox Extension: iframe document property read permission denied in same domain

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am creating a firefox addon. I am appending an `iframe` dynamically on page. I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024528/how-to-append-iframe-to-hosted-page-using-firefox-sdk-addon) url. But I am not able to get its `#document property` due to permission not defined.

I have also set cross domain permission in `package.json` file, however my iframe source page is in same domain.

```
 "permissions": {
    "unsafe-content-script": true,
    "private-browsing": true,
    "cross-domain-content": ["//sampleaddon/data/PopupTab.html"]
  },
```

Here `PopupTab.html` is source page of my iframe.

How can I access the #document property of iframe and update its content?

Every time I am getting error '`Permission denied to access document property`'

Comment: Try `iframe.contentDocument`

Comment: What context are you running this code from? Share your code its hard to help without it.